# Using express-socket.io-session, no session data is available in subsequent requests

Tags: express, socket.io, express-session

Here's my setup:

I have the session stuff in a file called `session-middleware.js`

```
var ExpressSession = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(ExpressSession);

expires_in_x_days = 5;
expiration_date = new Date();
expiration_date.setDate(expiration_date.getDate() + expires_in_x_days);

var session = ExpressSession({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,

    store: new RedisStore(),
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET_KEY,
    cookie: {
        expires: expiration_date,
        secure: false
    }
});

module.exports = session;
```

In my `bin/www` file I load it into my `app` object.

```
var shared_session_middleware = require('express-socket.io-session');
var session_middleware = require('../session-middleware');
app.use(session_middleware);
io.use(shared_session_middleware(session_middleware, {
    autoSave: true
}));
```

from what I can tell the configuration looks fine... and oddly this seemed to be working before.

When I go into redis, I can see a new session ID is being created for every request, and every refresh... I can load the session data in redis and see that the data I saved to it was persisted, but whenever I make a subsequent request... that data is no longer there

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "sess:2OjdEYYfmUmeMkJhfLAQHSKP6PQFrSsx"
2) "sess:lqVnA4dBun5J3Bk17lTkuKJmWQ4oCRCB"
3) "sess:OJrI2MzfSEaKMtUkHvBEwWbDZeBHJ5Q9"
4) "sess:Qd0NKKrlX0o0yu-f905NiqisFvSo4vWn"
5) "sess:D4CLLgMb3Q_LRzPLq_BIyvYKfLq7217e"
6) "sess:ZQE77OiW-F7XUro_XtBqgyp0gwwvae7b"
127.0.0.1:6379> key  "sess:ZQE77OiW-F7XUro_XtBqgyp0gwwvae7b"
(error) ERR unknown command 'key'
127.0.0.1:6379> get  "sess:ZQE77OiW-F7XUro_XtBqgyp0gwwvae7b"
"{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":431985563,\"expires\":\"2019-08-08T19:44:38.188Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"client_token\":\"a66af8647f2d9998bbe7e3acf00ea2a21fc74596\"}"
```

Comment: Probably not the problem you are current seeing, but it may hit you at some time. 
 This looks like you establish the `expiration_date` upon module startup.  What happens if your server stays running for 5 days.  Your  expiration date will be in the past.

Comment: A session is represented by a cookie in the browser.  Can you see the same session cookie from one request to another?  This is the key to getting reunited with a previous session object.  You can examine the cookie either in server-side middleware or by looking in the network tab in the Chrome debugger.

Comment: It doesn't look like the expiration date is an issue. There is a cookie named `io` that I'm seeing, it looks like socket.io is setting the cookie, it looks like an ID of some kind, and it changes on every refresh. That's the only thing that really looks like a kind of session ID.

Comment: `io` is not your session cookie.  It's probably called `connect.sid`.

Comment: I actually don't see anything like that in my cookies, that must be part of the issue then, the fact that there's no session id cookie.

Comment: Where is the request coming from?  A browser?  Some code that's not in a browser?  Is the browser configured to retain cookies?  Also, I'd suggest you use the [`maxAge`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#cookiemaxage) settings instead of the `expires` setting for your session cookie as that will automatically maintain a fixed amount of time in the future.  For 5 days, you can set `maxAge` to `5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` which is 5 days in milliseconds.

Comment: Yeah, the initial request comes from a browser, Chrome. Other cookies are set. I've set some cookies unrelated to the session, and those are appearing, so the browser is definitely retaining cookies. I'm using the `maxAge` parameter now as well.